# React js not found/blank page on refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this is a common question and I tried some of the answers in stackoverflow but in my case it didn't work yet.

I have an application in a shared hosting that I built using `yarn build`. When I refresh the page a `404` error is displayed as expected. So I read [this docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#docsNav) and created a .htaccess file with code below:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

and I added it to the root folder of the project. Everything is working now.

I have a second build for my admin panel located in subdirectory: https://example.com/Admin/Login and I serve the admin application on Login directory.

So I'm facing the same problem when I refresh the page. For example https://example.com/Admin/Dashboard.

If I refresh https://example.com/Admin/Login it loads the page and works fine but refreshing https://example.com/Admin/Dashboard I get a blank page.

I even built admin panel using the same .htaccess file located in `public` directory that is copied to build folder after build process but it doesn't work. I always get a blank page.

I read some [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually) but it's not working yet.

routes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from './pages/Login';
import Admin from './pages/Dashboard';

export default function Routes() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/Admin/Login" exact component={Login} />
                <Route path="/Admin/Dashboard" component={Manager} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );

}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "homepage": "https://example.com/Admin/Login",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there anything else that I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by moving Login folder content to the root (https://example.com/Admin) so that login form is loaded on it and I left .htaccess the same.